# Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'CustomCell *' from 'UITableViewCell *'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have this Warning: `Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'CustomCell *' from 'UITableViewCell *`

```
-(void)method:(id)sender{
    indexPath  = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0];
    CustomCell *customCell =  [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

"CustomCell" is a Subclass of `UITableViewCell!`. The Code works well but i want to remove this warnings.

Comment: Force to convert the type. `CustomCell *customCell =  (CustomCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: you could cast the return of the call to cellForRow... to the custom class... `CustomCell *customCell = (CustomCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: LOL Snap! you just pipped me :)

Comment: That's it :) Thx KudoCC & Cocoadelica